# Apps will not quit on Mac OS Sierra 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: shutdown, applications, force-quit

After getting my brand new 2016 MacBook Pro with Mac OS Sierra, I have noticed that apps such as Chrome, Mail, Spotify, anything really, randomly and intermittently do not shut down when I go to restart or shut down my computer. I have to force quit them to get them to shut down. I should not have to force quit apps just to shut down. This did not happen on my previous computer, the late 2012 iMac also OS Sierra.

What could be the root cause of the problem here?

Comment: I have the same problem here with Chrome and sometimes, Spotify.

Comment: You should probably vote this question up then.